# How to start VS 2010 from Run dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

Typing "devenv.exe" in my system's *Run* dialog starts VS 2008. I also have VS 2010 installed. How can I start VS 2010 from the *Run* dialog? I'm running Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

Neither should start on XP, it should complain that it cannot find the program.  Looks like the PATH environment variable in your system environment got tinkered with.  The VS installer doesn't mess with it.  Control Panel + System + Advanced + Environment variables to fix (iirc).  Logout + Login to make it effective.

Consider a desktop or quick launch shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of VS 2008 and 2010 directories in your PATH environment variable (if 2008 was installed before 2010, its directory is probably earlier in the PATH, so `devenv.exe` from 2008 is excuted). In Win XP, that would be My computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables.